# React Router Path

Tags: reactjs, path, react-router

I have a path.js file where it contains all the PATH Variable

```
export const PATH = {
USER: '/user/',
INFO: '/user/:user_id/'
}
```

when I try to access the PATH.INFO it doesn't go it's page but if I change INFO PATH it works.
Does /user/ and /user/:user_id/ mean same in react-router??

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, the answer of your question that weather the /user/ and /user/:user_id/
are same.  No they are not same /user mean this static path where /user/:user_id mean this path and after /:user_id this value is dynamic and could b any thing.  Also i notice that you have added an additional / at the end of your route.**

**Try this code it works**

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import TestCompOne from "./Components/TestCompOne/TestCompOne";
import TestCompTwo from "./Components/TestCompTwo/TestCompTwo";
import { PATH } from "./Route";

const app = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path={PATH.USER} exact component={TestCompOne} />
      <Route path={PATH.INFO} exact component={TestCompTwo} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default app;
```